# How to start with Salesforce Analytics Cloud on developer account?

Tags: analytics-cloud

I could only find [this](http://www.salesforce.com/analytics-cloud/overview/)

Can anyone please point me to more resource?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Now you can refer [trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/wave_analytics_basics) to get started with analytics wave. 
Get a Wave analytic enabled dev org from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/Wave-DF15-DE)
 and  Link to wave analytics pdf from [here](https://jira.talendforge.org/secure/attachment/74327/Analytics%20Cloud%20Implementation%20Guide.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Analytics Cloud is so new that it is near impossible to get a free "developer" version to play with.  I work for a Salesforce Partner and we couldn't even get a demo or trial.

Give the hype some time to die down and maybe you'll see some of the features become more accessible.

This is happening with [Pardot](http://www.pardot.com/) too.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Setup>> Wave Analytics >>Getting Started >> Enable Wave Analytics

Comment: Are you sure this is available in all developer accounts?

Comment: If you’re existing developer org has Analytics license, else create a new Dev org using this link :
https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/Wave-DF15-DE
Then Sign Up wave clicking on the link – https://startsurfingthewave.herokuapp.com/actions/enablement
Then you will get the above Reference in Setup.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to sign-up for a developer org once Salesforce Wave is GA(Generally Available). The current path for access is to be employed by a partner and to attend training sessions to gain access.

It is very limited on the license count so even with a partner the access is not guaranteed.